# Issues with controller in an ng-repeat communicating data to a different controller, depending on which ng-repeat element was clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I am trying to do the following:

I have two controllers that communicate to each other via a service ( Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GeorgiAngelov/a9WLr/1/).

**The idea:**

The idea is that modifying one controller will reflect in the other controller's fields, hence creating liveupdate functionality. However, current the SecondCtrl updates all 4 input fields at the same time, and vice-versa, and every single input updates all 4 the same time as well.

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

What I want to accomplish is the following: I want whenever I click on any of the input fields in controller one, I want it to populate the input box of controller two so then controller two can actually modify that input field that was originally clicked.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="project"> 
    <div ng-init=" data = [3,4,5,6]">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <input ng-model="thing.x"/ ng-repeat="singledata in data" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">            
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <input ng-model="someThing.x"/>             
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var projectModule = angular.module('project',[]);

projectModule.factory('theService', function() {  
    return {
        thing : {
            x : 100
        }
    };
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, theService) {
    $scope.thing = theService.thing;
    $scope.name = "First Controller";
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, theService) {   
    $scope.someThing = theService.thing; 
    $scope.name = "Second Controller!";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do something like this, to avoid repeating all the elements again. I've chaned around the `theService` API, as it was pretty generic and I wasn't really sure what its actual purpose was.

A working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/rpfAV/

```html
<body ng-app="project"> 
  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    <input ng-model="theService.things[key]"
      ng-repeat="(key, value) in theService.things" ng-click="edit(key)">
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    <input ng-model="theService.things[theService.editing]"/>           
  </div>
</body>
```

```javascript
var projectModule = angular.module('project',[]);

projectModule.factory('theService', function() {  
  return {
    editing: null,
    things : {
      w : 100,
      x : 200,
      y : 300,
      z : 400
    }
  };
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, theService) {
  $scope.theService = theService;
  $scope.name = "First Controller";
  $scope.edit = function(key) {
    theService.editing = key;
  };
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, theService) {   
  $scope.theService = theService;
  $scope.name = "Second Controller!";
}
```